# isEnabled binded to other button click

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't figure out which resource i am missing for this to work, I getting  messages ei namespace is not found.

```
        <Button 
         Name="btnEnter"
        Click="btnEnter_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource SignButtons}"
        FontFamily="Comic"
        FontSize="24"
        FontWeight="DemiBold"
        Grid.Column="3" 
        Height="51.562"
        Width="75"
        Margin="30,23.624,0,0"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Template="{DynamicResource EnterButton}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction 
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=btnMultiplication}" 
                    PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

here are the namespaces

```
<Window x:Class="Button_Template.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Button_Template"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
```

Comment: Show us your XML namespaces from the root element of the XAML, it should be pretty easy to spot.

Comment: Try adding this xmlns `xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions" `

Comment: I have added the namespace and now the error message is different - ChangePropertyAction  does not exist in "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.C‌​ore;assembly=Microso‌​ft.Expression.Intera‌​ctions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to follow these steps when you are adding something like `ChangePropertyAction`, `CallMethodAction`, etc...
1. Go to Blend and open your project, and select control where you want to insert that `ChangePropertyAction`
[image]

After you add `ChangePropertyAction` Blend will automaticly add xmlns extensions.
[image]

So you won't have to do it manualy. After you save that in blend, just go to VS and reaload your project and continue.

**IMPORTANT** Interaction will be added on selected control in your Objects and Timeline window.

Comment: I have followed your instructions,but when I drag the ChangePropertyAction onto myButton in Objects and TimeLine I get the message: create ChangePropertyAction in Button. I click but nothing happens. are there any key combinations to complete this operation?

Comment: Nothing special. i just select control, and in behaviors>>ChangePropertyAction use doubleClick and it automaticly add it to button.

Answer (score 2):

The `ChangePropertyAction` type is defined in Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll. It is not part of the .NET Framework but you can download this assembly using NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicrosoftExpressionInteractions/

Or you can download the Blend SDK from here and add a reference to it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801.

The XAML namespace mapping should then be:

```
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```