# Capture mouse click inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have created an UserControl which holds several labels. On the other side, I have a window (simple grid) which creates 6 instances of UserControl and places them in a single row.

My question is: how to fire up some action when user clicks on userControl (any part of it)?

I've tried to add `MouseDown` event handler inside UserControl `cs` file, and inside parent window during UserControl instance creation, but this doesn't have any effect. I've also tried adding `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeftButtonDownButton` but nothing of these worked.

This is part of parent window:

```
public BuyerSellerMonitorGridWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            // Add new column to grid
            this.grdBuyer.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

            // Create and add new transaction
            UserControl uc = new UserControl();
            uc.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += uc_MouseDown;
            System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(uc, 0);
            System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetColumn(uc, i);
            this.grdBuyer.Children.Add(uc);
        }
    }
```

This is UserControl:

```
public partial class Transaction: UserControl
    {
        public Transaction()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TransactionClicked()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

And this is `xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AssetStudio.Dialogs.Transaction"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AssetStudio.Dialogs"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <StackPanel x:Name="frameTransaction">
            <Label x:Name="lblClientName" Content="Client A" Height="35"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblDate" Content="2017/05/01"/>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="Curr Px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblCurrentPrice" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Trade Px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblTradePrice" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label4" Content="Qty Done" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblQuantityDone" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label6" Content="Size" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblSize" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label8" Content="Stk Px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblStockPrice" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="34">
            <Label x:Name="label10" Content="Delta" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblDelta" Content="Label" Margin="150,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: When you're using MouseEnter event on UserControl, you need make sure that you're inside the UserControl Content. I just used it here and it worked without any problem.

Comment: And I would also recommend using MVVM when programming with WPF, Then you will not need this behind-code. Instead bind properties to Xaml-controllers.

Comment: Can you show your UserControl? I cannot reproduce your problem on my side.

Comment: It still works, [look video](https://www.screencast.com/t/V9ppAn7N). TransactionClicked isn't invoked(not sure who should invoke it), but the handler uc_MouseDown is invoked when you click on your usercontrol. Note on video that clicks in lower part of the screen are not resulting in "test" because of control size.

Comment: If you want `TransactionClicked` to be invoked, then subscribe to event from usercontrol constructor: `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += TransactionClicked;`

Comment: Issue solved. This window is part of larger project, and I inherited from some custom base class, which somehow stopped mouse clicks to be captured. I changed base class to `Window` and it works fine. Thanks to everybody involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

in your UserControl:

include namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

and add `CallMethodAction`

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="UserControlClicked"
                             TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

`TargetObject="{Binding}"` tells you that this `UserControlClicked` method needs to be in your `ViewModel` that is `DataContext` of that `UserControl`.

where `UserControlClicked` is public method that you call when `MouseLeftButtonDown` is made on that control.

this is my UserControlViewModel just to show purpose,and to test.

```
public class UserControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControlViewModel()
    {
        Text = "Started!";
    }
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void UserControlClicked()
    {
        Text = "Clicked!";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Inside MainWindow i have instanced couple of this UserControl-s:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl1 />
        <local:UserControl1 />
        <local:UserControl1 />
        <local:UserControl1 />
        <local:UserControl1 />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

And this seems to be working as expected. UserControl that has beed clicked changed label content from Started! to Clicked!.

**EDIT:** Check this on how to add CallMethodAction via Blend:
[CallMethodAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270107/isenabled-binded-to-other-button-click/43272669#43272669)

Comment: Hi. `CallMethodAction` does not exists in `ei`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Add reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions and System.Windows.Interactivity

Comment: Usualy i add that CallMethodAction via Blend(on click) and it all all references and namespaces.